# How to do a bash foreach csv field to 'git submodule add'

Tags: git, bash, csv, git-submodules

I have no idea how to write Bash and after googling around for a while, I'm in no better position to achieve what I need.
I have a csv file consisting of a list of git submodules and their paths-to-be in the super project:

```
git://github.com/demo/git-repo.git, extensions/git-repo
git://github.com/demo/another-repo.git, extensions/another-repo
```

I would like to have a bash script which would read each line of the file, put each part of the line (separated by the comma) into the following command

```
git submodule add $1 $2
```

`$1` being the git:// part and `$2` being the extensions/ part

I need to be able to pass the filename of the csv file to the script, and not have it hardcoded in the script. If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it as I have over 50 of these submodules to add regularly, and I'm fed up with writing it out one by one.

Cheers.

Comment: Depending on the actual contents of those repositories, you might consider some recursive submodules, bundling up those over 50 into a more manageable number.

Comment: I would love to, but they are all separate extensions to a CMS system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only have 50 of these submodules, you can create a `bash` script to do this

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"

while IFS="," read one two
do
  git submodule add "$one" "$two"
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: So I could do between 20 and 200 with this if I wanted then?

Comment: yes, as long as you have 20-200 of each of these separated by commas like in your sample. It should be fine.