# Converting cloned git repositories into submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project which is a git repository, and inside that project I have some cloned git repositories.

The directory structure is like this.

```
main-project
    -other_project (cloned git repository)
    -another_project (cloned git repository)
```

When I tried to clone main-project into another system, it only has empty directories for other_project and another_project.

I know that I should have used `git submodule` to add those repositories in the first place. Since I didn't, is there any way to fix the mess I've made ?

There are about 15 repositories inside (which should be submodules), so a way to "bulk convert" all those repositories into submodules would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a script, a bit like in "[How to do a bash foreach csv field to 'git submodule add'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776984/how-to-do-a-bash-foreach-csv-field-to-git-submodule-add)", except, for each nested repo, you would need to extract the upstream repo url ([`git remote origin`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))

Then add the `.gitmodules`  file created in your parent repo by those ["`submodule add`"](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), and commit.

You will be able to [clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) (with `--recursive` option) your parent repo, and get back all those submodules.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do `git submodule add ./path/to/subdirectory ./path/to/subdirectory`, which will add the repositories as submodules, but with the incorrect origin url. You can then manually edit `.git/config` and replace the urls with the correct urls (i.e. the ones you cloned from).